# How to get a pre-signed URL that downloads file with http compression

Tags: amazon-s3

Here is my code in node.js:

```js
    const downloadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: 'key to a large json file',
    });
```

One got the URL, I want to download a very large JSON file stored in S3 from browser. Since it is large, I would like to use HTTP compression which would compress a 20MB JSON to less than 1MB. I could not find anywhere how to do it or whether it is at all possible with S3 APIs.

I also tried to do below when using the signed URL to download file and it seems not work.

```js
    const dataRes = await fetch(downloadURL, {
      headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      },
      method: 'GET',
    });
```

Hope somebody could help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are the files in S3 already compressed and you want to just download them? or the files in s3 are not compressed and you want to compress on the fly ? Because i don't beleive S3 supports the second one, we may need cloudfront on top of S3 to do this.

Comment: Thanks and yes. I figured that out as well. Put my notes into the answer, hoping helpful to others.

Answer (score 6):

After doing some study, I have resolved this. Post here and hope it is helpful to others.

- You cannot ask S3 to compress file on the fly when `getObject` or using signed URL to `getObject`
- You would have to save the zipped file into S3 in the first place. In Linux, using  below command to do it:

  ```sh
  gzip -9 <file to compress>
  ```
- Upload the zipped file to S3
- Use below code to generate the signed URL:

  ```js
      const downloadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'key to a large zipped json file',
        ResponseContentEncoding: 'gzip',
        ResponseContentType: 'application/json',
      });
  ```
- Use below code to download from the signed URL:

  ```js
    const res = await fetch(downloadurl);
    const jsonData = await res.json();
  ```

Comment: For Ruby, `bucket.object(id).presigned_url(:get, response_content_encoding: 'gzip')` seems to be enough.